# Edit external JS script in browser, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

When I open the Inspector I can view the HTML source of my web page. I can then edit the HTML and actually see it taking effect on the browser. Is it possible to do the same for an externally loaded script, e.g. some logic loaded via a  tag?

I have some validation happening in there, and while I know that validation should happen server-side as well, I would just like to test it and play around. I have tried doing this in Safari, but it does not seem possible in that browser to edit a js script that was loaded separately. But is it possible in something like Chrome or in some other way?

Sorry if this is. a newbie question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called **Overrides** and you can find it in the **Sources** Panel.

Go to Sources and expand the tab where you see "Page, Filesystem, Overrides ← ...".
Activate Overrides and confirm the modal asking write to file.  Select a desired folder, call it i.e: `chrome-overrides`.
Go back to Elements, find the `<script src="` you want to override, right click → *Reveal in Sources panel*.
From there, edit the file and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save your changes.
Refresh the page.